# How to reset the max file size which Office Web apps supports

Tags: powershell, office-web-components

I have an office web apps server run on Windows Server 2008 R2 that help me transforming office files(word, ppt, excel). But I get error when the file size exceed 10MB. I have searched the Internet, But got no answer.

the closest aticle is http://blogs.technet.com/b/sammykailini/archive/2014/06/25/office-web-apps-2013-increase-excel-workbook-size-from-the-10-mb-limit.aspx, but it do still not work.

Has somebody did this work before ? I need help. I must support at least 20MB file's transformation.

and there is the configuration:
[image]

Comment: This is definitely a server question; there's no way to change it from the client.  You might get more traction on http://serverfault.com, which has more IT folks.  SO is full of programmers who don't know much about server administration.

Comment: Probably set the parameter to -1 and restart the services (or the whole server to make sure the new config has been applied).